# Julia Flux error: SGD optimiser is undefined

Tags: julia, flux.jl

I want to use the `SGD` optimiser in Flux as shown in the Julia Academy tutorial for *Deep Learning with Flux.jl*. [This](https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/LS4OC8QtTG2IblWcQEtg) the notebook they provided in which they use the SGD optimizer as:

```
opt = SGD(params(model))
```

However when I run SGD I get:

```
ERROR: UndefVarError: SGD not defined
```

This is my output when I run `?SGD`:

```
search: SGD AMSGrad Signed signed Unsigned unsigned sigmoid issetgid logsigmoid StringIndexError isassigned significand

Couldn't find SGD
Perhaps you meant SGD, Set, Sys, GC, Some, sec, sin, sum, LSTM, csc, esc, isa, ans, abs, cis, cos, eps, ARGS, Pkg, GRU, RNN, cpu, elu, f32, f64, gpu, σ, !, !=, !== or %
  No documentation found.

  Binding SGD does not exist.
```

As you can see it is still showing SGD in the *Perhaps you meant* line.

I do not get an error when I run other optimizers also shown in the tutorial such as ADAM. I am using Flux v0.10.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tutorial uses an outdated version of `Flux`.

In version v0.10.0 of Flux, Flux has deprecated usage of `SGD` in favor of `Descent` which is just a more optimised version of the Standard Gradient Descent algorithm.

More information on the `Descent` optimizer can be found in the [documentation](https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/training/optimisers/).

Also as a side-note, Flux no longer needs to pass `params(model)` into the optimizer instead it takes it as a separate argument when training.

```
# New Way
Flux.train!(loss, params(model), data, optimizer)
```